# Can I filter on request.user when using Django generic views?

Tags: django, filter, view, generics

I want to do something like this (from my `urls.py`), but I don't know if it's possible to get the user making the request:

```
    url(r'^jobs/(page(?P<page>[0-9]+)/)?$',
        object_list, {'queryset': Job.objects.filter(user=request.user), 
                      'template_name': 'shootmpi/molecule_list.html'},
        name='user_jobs'),
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write a wrapper function that calls object_list with the required queryset.

In urls.py:

```
url(r'^(page(?P<page>[0-9]+)/)?$', 'views.user_jobs', name='user_jobs')
```

In views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list

def user_jobs(request, page):
    job_list=Job.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return object_list(request, queryset=job_list,
        template_name='shootmpi/molecule_list.html',
        page=page)
```

There's a [good blog post by James Bennett](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/nov/16/django-tips-get-most-out-generic-views/) on using this technique.

Comment: I was trying to get around creating my own view, but just wrapping object_list sounds like a reasonable idea

Comment: Good answer -- You can do much more with generic views when you take them out of urls.py, and use them inside your own view functions

Comment: Good link! I had always considered generic views to be something that you just use in urls.py.