# Is it possible acess request data into a django generic list view?

Tags: django, list, generics, view, request

I need to have access to some request data (username) into a template used in a generic list view. I serched django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/) but this subject is not so clear (to me) at a first glance.

My situation is like this:

```
**urls.py:**

from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

...

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^pattern.html', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="template_name.html")),
    ...
)

** template_name.html **

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}My title{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>My heading</h2>
<a href="{% url path.to.my.view.view_name_1 %}">link text 1</a> | 
<a href="{% url path.to.my.view.view_name_2 %}">link text 2</a> | 
<a href="{% url path.to.my.view.view_name_3 request.username  %}">link for {{username}}</a> | 
{% endblock %}
```

Here (template_name.html) is where I want to use the request data. To compose a link to another view passing as parameter request.user

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539697/can-i-filter-on-request-user-when-using-django-generic-views) post says tels somthing about generics but its not exactly what i need.

Comment: What data are you looking for in particular?

Answer (score 2):

`{{ user.username }}` is always available in a generic view, because of the `auth` context processor. If you need anything else from the request, you'll need to add the [`request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) context processor.

Comment: Ok. I'm gonna give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: I was having some trouble using my template in flat views (views.py) but reading [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context) I learnt it is necessary to pass the context to the template when using render_to_response function.